# Can a low current (low power) solar panel charge a battery?

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, charge

I have a solar panel that provides max 7V and average 5.5V under the sun. But it cannot produce enough current even for a little 3V DC motor. Can this solar panel charge a 3V battery? Or maybe two 3V batteries?

Comment: Look at the specs of your rechargeable batteries and see what charging current they require. Similarly, check the specs of your solar panel and see what current it can provide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as the solar panel can provide an output voltage higher than the battery voltage, and current higher than the battery's rate of self-discharge, it'll charge the battery.

Comment: Interesting concept there - battery self-discharge. I guess that was something I've never really considered before. Since something like an AA battery is claimed to last decades, this rate must be quite slow?

Comment: @sherrellbc A AA battery that is claimed to last decades would be an alkaline battery (i.e. non-rechargeable). Rechargeable batteries in general have a much more noticeable self-discharge rate. It is temp and SOC dependent. For Li-ion's it's 1.5-2% according to manufacturers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion_battery#Self-discharge

Comment: The [Wikipedia "self-discharge" article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/self-discharge) implies that primary alkaline batteries typically have a shelf life of 5 years. The best (lowest) self-discharge rates in that article are 2% per month -- i.e., 22% per year.